# can't set active class in CSS menu

Tags: jquery

I have a CSS menu where I want to set the class to "active" of the clicked menu item. I can "find" the clicked item and try to set the active class

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

but it doesn't stick.

Why?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/8xp2fsu7/7/)

```js
$(document).on("click", "#newSubmission", function() {
  makeActive(this);
});

function makeActive(obj) {
  var tid = $(obj).attr("id");
  $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
    if (tid === $(this).attr("id")) {
      $("#result").append("found match<br>")
      $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $("#result").append("no match<br>")
    }
  });
}

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "Menu",
      breakpoint: 100,
      format: "multitoggle"
    });

    $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

    var foundActive = false,
      activeElement, linePosition = 0,
      menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"),
      lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
        foundActive = true;
      }
    });

    if (foundActive === false) {
      activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
    }

    defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

    defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

    menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
    menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
      activeElement = $(this);
      lineWidth = activeElement.width();
      linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
    }, function() {
      menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
      menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #b70102;
  width: auto;
}

#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:hover>ul {
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover>ul>li {
  height: 32px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li:hover>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right>ul>li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li.has-sub>a::after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-line {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
    <li id="editHome"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li id="newSubmission"><a href="#">new submission</a></li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart"></i> reports</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dr.&#39;s notes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">number of samples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">arrival temperatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">culture count</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">summaries</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">% of target</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">stored motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">morphology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TSD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSA report for TSD date range</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">culture summary  by submission</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub active"><a href="#">setup</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">canned comments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="logOff"><a href="#">log off</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>
  click "new submission" and it should keep the "active" class
</p>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: You never call `addClass()` in your code.

Comment: oops, sorry I edited too much.
I've added it but same result.

Comment: What happened to the stack snippet I added to the question? Why did you go back to jsfiddle?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't stick? Inspecting the element using developer tools shows the active class still there.

Comment: Click "new submission". The white line should stay over it when clicked. If you manually add 'class=active' to its <li> it works

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates that the line should stay over it when clicked. Your snippet starting with `$("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {` only happens on page load. Which is why your white line stays when active is there on page load.

Comment: The white line is implemented by the `.hover()` method, it has nothing to do with the `active` class.

Comment: the hover method is a different thing going on.

Comment: I've manually added the class "active" to the SETUP tab. Now when you run the snippet, SETUP has the white line "stuck" over it. I want it to stick on whatever is clicked. In the snippet, I've bound "NEW SUBMISSION" so that it should remove the class "active" from the other menu items, and apply it to "NEW SUBMISSION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone quick and dirty on this there would be more elegant solutions than this but this will get you working.

The main source of your problem is that you set the starting postion for the white line on page load. You don't modify this anywhere else. The `active` css class is pretty much irrelevant here.

What I've done is moved the click handler and `makeActive` method into the document ready method to give them all the same scope. Then in the `makeActive` method I reset the width and position parameters.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", "#newSubmission", function() {
      makeActive(this);
    });

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "Menu",
      breakpoint: 100,
      format: "multitoggle"
    });

    $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

    var foundActive = false,
      activeElement, linePosition = 0,
      menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"),
      lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
        foundActive = true;
      }
    });

    if (foundActive === false) {
      activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
    }

    defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

    defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

    menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
    menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
      activeElement = $(this);
      lineWidth = activeElement.width();
      linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
    }, function() {
      menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
      menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
    });

    function makeActive(obj) {
      var tid = $(obj).attr("id");
      $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
        if (tid === $(this).attr("id")) {
          $("#result").append("found match<br>")
          $(this).addClass("active");
          //This is the new stuff - reset the defaults
          defaultWidth = lineWidth = $(this).width();
          defaultPosition = linePosition = $(this).position().left;
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("active");
          $("#result").append("no match<br>")
        }
      });
    }

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #b70102;
  width: auto;
}

#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:hover>ul {
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover>ul>li {
  height: 32px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li:hover>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right>ul>li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li.has-sub>a::after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-line {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
    <li id="editHome"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li id="newSubmission"><a href="#">new submission</a></li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart"></i> reports</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dr.&#39;s notes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">number of samples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">arrival temperatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">culture count</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">summaries</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">% of target</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">stored motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">morphology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TSD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSA report for TSD date range</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">culture summary  by submission</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub active"><a href="#">setup</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">canned comments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="logOff"><a href="#">log off</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>
  click "new submission" and it should keep the "active" class
</p>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to utilise the `active` class, you can do the following. I think this is better.

What I've done here is on exit hover condition, find the active element and set the line based on that. If there is no active element, we fall back to the initial defaults.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#newSubmission", function() {
  makeActive(this);
});

function makeActive(obj) {
  var tid = $(obj).attr("id");
  $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
    if (tid === $(this).attr("id")) {
      $("#result").append("found match<br>")
      $(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $("#result").append("no match<br>")
    }
  });
}

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
      title: "Menu",
      breakpoint: 100,
      format: "multitoggle"
    });

    $("#cssmenu").prepend("<div id='menu-line'></div>");

    var foundActive = false,
      activeElement, linePosition = 0,
      menuLine = $("#cssmenu #menu-line"),
      lineWidth, defaultPosition, defaultWidth;

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        activeElement = $(this);
        foundActive = true;
      }
    });

    if (foundActive === false) {
      activeElement = $("#cssmenu > ul > li").first();
    }

    defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

    defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

    menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
    menuLine.css("left", linePosition);

    $("#cssmenu > ul > li").hover(function() {
      activeElement = $(this);
      lineWidth = activeElement.width();
      linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
      menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
      menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
    }, function() {
      //New Stuff -- Find the active element
      activeElement = $("#cssmenu .active");  
      //Set based on active element fulling back to defaultt  if there is none
      menuLine.css("left",  activeElement.length > 0 ? activeElement.position().left :  defaultPosition);
      menuLine.css("width", activeElement.length > 0 ? lineWidth = activeElement.width(): defaultWidth);
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #b70102;
  width: auto;
}

#menu-line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.align-right>ul>li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a,
#cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #f3f3f3;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:hover>ul {
  right: 0;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .2s ease;
  -o-transition: height .2s ease;
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover>ul>li {
  height: 32px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul li:hover>ul>li {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul li a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center>ul>li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-right>ul>li {
  float: none;
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li:hover>a,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen>ul>li.has-sub>a::after,
#cssmenu.small-screen ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-line {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.15);
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 11px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 99;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu.small-screen.select-list {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/menumaker/menumaker.min.js"></script>

<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
    <li id="editHome"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li id="newSubmission"><a href="#">new submission</a></li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart"></i> reports</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Dr.&#39;s notes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">number of samples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">arrival temperatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">culture count</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">summaries</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">% of target</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">stored motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">morphology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">motility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TSD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSA report for TSD date range</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">culture summary  by submission</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub active"><a href="#">setup</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">canned comments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="logOff"><a href="#">log off</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>
  click "new submission" and it should keep the "active" class
</p>
<div id="result">

</div>
```